# select2 tags not working with json url single select

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I need select2 configured so it will allow 'custom entries', i.e. user entries that are not in the list provided. select2 provides for this with the tags option which seems to work flawlessly, except for some reason I cannot get it to work with my situation. It will allow the user entry, but does not actually allow the user to click on it. Test link below. (it breaks any selection when typing an entry in).

http://www.tinkeringtester.com/s2test.html

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
        <label for="testitem" class="control-label">Items</label>
        <select name="testitem" id="testitem" class="form-control"><option></option></select>   
    </div>
```

jQuery

$.fn.modal.Constructor.prototype.enforceFocus = function () {};

```
$('#testitem').select2({
    width: '100px',
    placeholder: 'Find Item',
    allowClear: true,
    SingleSelection: true,
    tags: true,
    ajax: {
        url: 's2test.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        //delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
            $('#testitem').empty();
            var d = new Date();
            var n = d.getTime();
            return {
                q: params.term,
                n: n
            };
        },
        processResults: function (data) {
            return { results: data };
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was causing this. By removing the following line of code it now functions properly. (This line of code was added because each lookup would only add to the contents that were already existing. However when I removed the line the contents are not duplicating and I can select custom addictions now.)

```
$('#testitem').empty();
```

Answer (score 0):

As last answer shows, this solves the issue..

```
$(".LocalitySelectMul").empty();
$(".LocalitySelectMul").select2({
    placeholder: "Select Localities",
    data: locadata,
});
```